# DVWP ASP.NET Filter for all pages

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter, dropdown

I have created a drop down along with DVWP as described in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/949d4443-58a4-464b-9603-e4c280740650.

However I see one major problem with it. I have around 300 items in the list and I am displaying only 30 per page. Now the filter works only if the selected item from dropdown is in the current page.

Is there anyway to apply filter to all the pages instead of only current page? For example, in the dropdown if 'Foo' is selected and 'Foo' related items are in the current page, it works very well. However, if the 'Foo' related items are in 5th page but not current page, then the filter doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.